# Can I insert PHP code into CakePHP based site?

Tags: php, cakephp

I made some pages in PHP, it's all working okay, it have database connect, all of those is okay.
But then I get info that I'm building that for CakePHP based site...

Those pages are just one part of pages, headers are "included" in files...
But now... Are they included okay with CakePHP?

Can this be mixed?

I know that CakePHP is actually PHP but it have some weird codes...

Can I integrate those parts of pages written in PHP into CakePHP written page?

Please HELP!

Comment: This can't be answered without seeing the code you want to insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP is still PHP but it follows a specific programming model called Model View Controller, which means the website is separated in three main parts, database data, templates and php code, which is structured in many different folders, **you can mix your code with it BUT you will probably have a hard time getting directories, files right**.

Answer (score 0):

Some documentation and examples are more capable of answering your question: http://book.cakephp.org/